# xmlとxslのファイルを使っています．属性の絞り込み方法を教えてください

Tags: xml, xsl

属性の絞り込み方法を教えてほしいです．
xmlとxslのファイルのコードは以下の通りです.
表示させようとしても何も表示されません．

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="tabemono.xsl"?>
<tabemono>
  <item>
    <title>カレー</title>
    <url resource="http://cookpad.com/category/26"/>
  </item>
</tabemono>

<!-- language: lang-xsl -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
  <ul>  
    <xsl:value-of select="books/item/url[@resource]" />
  </ul>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xsl:value-of select="books/item/url[@resource]" />
```

の代わりに、XPath表現を

```
<xsl:value-of select="tabemono/item/url/@resource" />
```

にしたら、出力結果は下記のようになります。

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ul>http://cookpad.com/category/26</ul>
```